# Delete history from a specific computer

Tags: google-chrome, history

I use chrome at both work, home computers, phones etc... and didn't realize the history was being stored locally on the work computer.  I've turned off the sync settings so it will no longer be syncing at work, but I'd like to make sure there are no local files containing my browser and search history on this machine, while keeping the browser and search history on all my other devices.

Is there a way to specifically delete browser and search history from one device?

Comment: Yes, just go to chrome history (Ctrl +H), then click on clear browsing data, and choose "the beginning of time" then tick all options and click on Clear browsing data. this will delete all browsing data history on the device that you're applying it to. Other devices won't be affected from this since you've already disabled the sync option and it won't sync anything on this device.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to Google Chrome settings (chrome://settings/)
2. Click "Disconnect your Google Account..."
3. Enable the option "Also clear your history, bookmarks, settings, and other Chrome data stored on this device"
4. Re-connect your Google account as you did originally, but this time select only the types of personal data that you would like to have stored on your work computer.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Delete your browsing history***
>
> You can delete all or some of your Chrome browsing history. If you're signed in to Chrome on multiple computers or devices, deleting your browsing history will take effect on all other devices.
>
> ***See your full web history***
>
> Your History page shows the websites you've visited on Chrome in the last 90 days. It doesn’t store pages from secure websites, those you've visited in incognito mode, or those you've already deleted from your browsing history.
>
> Here's how to see your full browsing history:
>
> **Computer**
>
> 1. In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu.
> 2. Select **History**.
>
> **Mobile device**
>
> 1. Open the Chrome menu.
> 2. Touch **History**.
>
> ***Clear all of your history***
>
> Here's how to delete your entire browsing history:
>
> **Computer**
>
> 1. In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu.
> 2. Select **History**.
> 3. Click the button **Clear browsing data**. A dialog will appear.
> 4. From the drop-down menu, select how much history you want to delete. To clear your entire browsing history, select **the beginning of time**.
> 5. Check the boxes for the data you want Chrome to clear, including “browsing history."
> 6. Click the button **Clear browsing data**.
>
> **Android device**
>
> 1. Open the Chrome menu. It could be an icon or a button.
> 2. Touch **History**.
> 3. At the bottom, touch **Clear Browsing Data**.
> 4. Check the box **Clear browsing history**. It may be checked by default.
> 5. Uncheck any other boxes you don't want to delete.
> 6. Touch **Clear**.
>
> **iPhone or iPad**
>
> 1. Open the Chrome menu.
> 2. Touch **History**.
> 3. At the bottom, touch **Clear Browsing Data**.
> 4. Touch **Clear Browsing History**.
> 5. Confirm your choice.
> 6. Touch **Done**.
>
> ***Delete specific items from your history***
>
> You can manually delete parts of your history. To search for something specific, use the search bar at the top.
>
> Here's how to delete certain parts of your browsing history:
>
> **Computer**
>
> 1. In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu.
> 2. Select **History**.
> 3. Check the box next to each webpage that you want to remove from your History.
> 4. At the top of the page, click the button **Remove selected items**.
> 5. A confirmation box will appear. Click **Remove**.
>
> Remove specific thumbnails from New Tab page
>
> To see your most frequently visited sites, open a New Tab page. To remove a thumbnail, hover over it and click the **X** in the top-right corner.
>
> **Mobile device**
>
> 1. Open the Chrome menu.
> 2. Touch **History**.
> 3. Touch the **X** next to the specific entry you want deleted.
>
> Remove specific thumbnails from the New Tab page
>
> To see your most frequently visited sites, open a New Tab page. To remove a thumbnail, touch and hold it. Then select **Remove**.
>
> ***Browse privately***
>
> If you don’t want Chrome to save your browsing history at all, you can switch to incognito mode.

Source: [Delete your browsing history](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95589?hl=en)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Links can become invalid thus making your answer no longer helpful.

Comment: @CharlieRB While, in general, I think you're right, I don't think Google will remove that information about its flagship software, unless they move it, in which case they would redirect the link, Charlie. In any case, I've followed your advice.

Comment: since you had turn off syncing with other account  for google chrome before  deleting the history of searched website,it  wont affect already synced history to all other devices.so you can go ahead by deleting history you can you use clear browsing data.